# How to add custom field in shipping method using woocommerce wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to **add custom field in shipping method** using woocommerce wordpress

Please see my screenshot [image: shipping method screenshot]

Comment: Please share us what have you tried so far.

Comment: i want to add shipping method description and one extra field for shipping day @Nilambar

See screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqtPp.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2TH4.png

Comment: Ok, requirement is clear. Please share us code you are trying to implement. Which hooks are you using. like that.

Comment: @Nilambar ok this is woo-commerce default functionality and i want to add custom field description and one other field got it ?

Answer (score 9):

Please try this code.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'dimative_shipping_instance_form_fields_filters' ) ) {
    /**
     * Shipping Instance form add extra fields.
     *
     * @param array $settings Settings.
     * @return array
     */
    function dimative_shipping_instance_form_add_extra_fields( $settings ) {
        $settings['shipping_extra_field_title'] = array(
            'title'       => esc_html__( 'Shipping method title', 'zincheco' ),
            'type'        => 'text',
            'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Please add shipping method title', 'zincheco' ),
            'description' => '',
        );

        $settings['shipping_extra_field_description'] = array(
            'title'       => esc_html__( 'Shipping method description', 'zincheco' ),
            'type'        => 'textarea',
            'placeholder' => esc_html__( 'Please add your shipping method description', 'zincheco' ),
            'description' => '',
        );

        return $settings;
    }

    /**
     * Shipping instance form fields.
     */
    function dimative_shipping_instance_form_fields_filters() {
        $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();
        foreach ( $shipping_methods as $shipping_method ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_instance_form_fields_' . $shipping_method->id, 'dimative_shipping_instance_form_add_extra_fields' );
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_init', 'dimative_shipping_instance_form_fields_filters' );
}
```

Comment: Great. It works but how can I show it on my shipping methods label?

Answer (score 3):

In case if someone is looking how to get the value using @Өлзийбат-Нансалцог code example. I was able to retrieve it this way:

```
//Get Shipping rate object
//$method->id is the ID of the shipping method. 
//In my case I used that in cart-shipping.php template
$WC_Shipping_Rate = new WC_Shipping_Rate($method->id); 

// Returned value is flat_rate:1
$shipping_rate_id = $WC_Shipping_Rate->get_id(); 

//Replacing : with underscore to have the id in format of flat_rate_1
$shipping_rate_id = str_replace(':', '_', $shipping_rate_id);

//Get the description field value
//Since the value is stored inside options table use get_option() method
get_option('woocommerce_'.$shipping_rate_id.'_settings')['shipping_extra_field_description']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for getting the value.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'dimative_shipping_method_description' ) ) {
    /**
     * Function will print shipping method description.
     *
     * @param object $method Shipping method object.
     * @param int    $index Shipping method index.
     * @return void
     */
    function dimative_shipping_method_description( $method, $index ) {
        $dimative_method_fields       = get_option( 'woocommerce_' . $method->method_id . '_' . $method->instance_id . '_settings' );
        $dimative_method_allowed_html = array(
            'p'      => array(
                'class' => array(),
            ),
            'strong' => array(),
            'b'      => array(),
            'a'      => array(
                'href' => array(),
            ),
            'span'   => array(
                'class' => array(),
            ),
        );
        // Shipping method custom description.
        if ( $dimative_method_fields['shipping_extra_field_description'] ) {
            ?>
            <div class="method-description"><?php echo wp_kses( $dimative_method_fields['shipping_extra_field_description'], $dimative_method_allowed_html ); ?></div>
            <?php
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_rate', 'dimative_shipping_method_description', 1, 2 );
}
```